# Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition to 2010 express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have developed a windows application in VS 2010 Professional Edition. When I tried open that project and build in expression edition, It is showing error. I could not open the project. Is there any compatible issue? If there means, what I have to do?

Thanks,

Comment: The error itself as with error codes and exact description would be very helpful. Please be thorough with giving information about your problems when asking questions.

Comment: The client machine got like following message - "This computer program is protected by copyright law and international treaties. Unauthorized reproduction or distribution of this program, or any portion of it, may result in serve civil and criminal penalties, and will be prosecuted to the maximum extent possible under the law."

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Profession the edition for professional or I say full usage potential that includes many other stuff that are not a part of Express edition (e.g. Express edition does not allow third-party add-ins), that’s why VS Professional is around  3~4GB while Express comes around ~600Mb of setup.

Point is by migrating from Professional `->` Express you are going backwards and usually project transfers are supported fro up gradation not degradation, there might my different functions/libraries your project is using from Professional that are not a part of Express edition hence you are receiving  this error.

Check for a complete functionality difference chart in between two editions, and from there you than easily find out that if there is any functional that is a part of project in Pro edition but is not supported by Express edition.